# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Quiero crear un formulario reactivo con ionic (6.9.0) Angular(9.1.7) llevo con este error un par de días y no doy con la solución ni se porque es:

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app.module.ts he añadido los import ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
```

---

registro.page.ts con formbuilder agrupo los campos del form, con validator hago las validaciones

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
     import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
       @Component({
       selector: 'app-registro',
        templateUrl: './registro.page.html',
       styleUrls: ['./registro.page.scss'],
     })
export class RegistroPage implements OnInit {

  get name(){
    return this.registrationForm.get('name');
  }
  get email(){
    return this.registrationForm.get('email');
  }
  get password(){
    return this.registrationForm.get('password');
  }

  public errorMessages = {
    name:[
      { type: 'required', message:'Nick requerido'},
      { type: 'minlength', message:'mínimo 4 caracteres'},
      { type: 'maxlength', message:'maxímo 12 caracteres'},
    ],

    email:[
      { type: 'required', message:'Email requerido'},
      { type: 'pattern', message:'Ingrese un correo electronico valido'},
    ],

    password:[
      { type: 'required', message:'Password requerido'},
      { type: 'minlength', message:'mínimo 6 caracteres'},
      { type: 'maxlength', message:'maxímo 12 caracteres'},
    ]
 };

 private emailPattern:string='^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$';

 registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   name:['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(12)]],
   email:['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]],
   password:['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(12)]]
 });


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public submit(){
    console.log(this.registrationForm.value);
  }
}
```

---

registro.page.html formulario con los campos name, email y password. [formGroup]="registrationForm"

```
<form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
      <ion-list style="background: transparent;" class="background-input">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Nombre</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="name" autocapitalize inputmode="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngFor="let error of errorMessages.name">
          <ng-container *ngIf="name.hasError(error.type) && (name.dirty || name.touched)">
            <small class="error-message">{{error.message}}</small>
          </ng-container>
        </div>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="email" inputmode="email"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngFor="let error of errorMessages.email">
          <ng-container *ngIf="email.hasError(error.type) && (email.dirty || email.touched)">
            <small class="error-message">{{error.message}}</small>
          </ng-container>
        </div>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">password</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="password" inputmode="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngFor="let error of errorMessages.password">
          <ng-container *ngIf="password.hasError(error.type) && (password.dirty || password.touched)">
            <small class="error-message">{{error.message}}</small>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </ion-list>

      <ion-button [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid" type="submit" color="tertiary" expand="block" class="ion-margin-top" >
        Registrarme
        <ion-icon slot="end" name="create"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
```

He estado mirando en problemas parecidos que hay en stackoverflow pero no me resuelven el error.
Cualquier ayuda sera bien recibida.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 5):

He dado con el error!
En ionic al generar una page con el comando:

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Genera una carpeta con estos archivos

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues en el archivo registro.module.ts es donde hay que hacer el import siguiente:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RegistroPageRoutingModule
  ],
```

---

Mi error era que yo hacia el import en al archivo app.module.ts. Hecha esta corrección el formulario reactivo funciona correctamete.

Comment: Gracias por documentar tu error, yo tenía exactamente el mismo problema, ya tenia como 3 horas atorado y puse todo igual a como tu lo tienes y ya salí de ese problema, ahroa me pide que le ponga una instancia de FormGroup pero creo que algo me está faltando en el grupo

Comment: Muchas gracias, también estuve varias horas buscando este error y por suerte di con tu pregunta y respuesta :)